# Documentation about file systems for flash drives

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive

My bachelor work is about file systems for flash drives. What can I read and where can I find documentation about this?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linux-usb.org/ would be a good start, but your question is a bit too open-ended.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The most common file system for USB flash drives is [FAT16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT16) or [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT32). Consequently, 
reading their description is a good place to start.

Comment: Although using either of those two FS on flash is a *sin*.

Comment: @Blank I don't get your comment. FAT is the ONLY file system supported by many devices such as photo / video cameras, music players, smartphones etc. You can call it whatever you like, but this is a de-facto standard.

Comment: From a technical POV, given how flash works (big erase blocks, small read blocks, larger write blocks) and given how FAT works (clusters), using FAT on flash is technically horrific.

Comment: That's true, but on the other hand flash memory (besides SSD but this is not what we are discussing) is cheap, flash cards die faster due to problems with contacts or with slot engineering, rather than due to fault of some pages. And as FAT code implementation is cheap and simple and the FS provides some undelete opportunities, who cares about not optimal format?